# Is dual directory integrations possible with Windows?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, ldap

In the Mac world, you can integrate OS X systems with dual directories so that OS X looks towards Active Directory for authentication and OpenLDAP for OS X managed preferences.

Is the following set-up possible in the Windows world: I'd like to utilise LDAP for domain authentication and Active Directory for managed preferences.

Is this possible?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to do this explicity with LDAP. [Active Directory can create a trust with an external Kerberos domain](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731297.aspx) which could be somewhere to start. The computer can then be a member of your Active Directory domain, but authenticate from a different trust.

Comment: I suspect this is not possible. Windows logons use kerberos for authentication - most if not all of the authorization mechanisms will be expecting kerberos tokens, which a native ldap won't provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows machines have the capability to delegate (trust) authentication to a single Active Directory (or old-style Windows NT) domain in a process called "joining" the domain. That domain could have trust relationships with other domains or Kerberos realms, but that's a relationship between the Domain Controller computers and the foreign domains or realms. The client still trusts a single domain.

There is no concept of "managed preferences", per se. The closest thing is probably Active Directory Group Policy. The client will apply computer Group Policy from the domain it is joined to. If a user from a trusted domain logs on, however, Group Policy for the user will be processed from the domain the user account is located within. That's likely as close as you're going to get to what OS X allows.